# My PC disconnects after i turn on the (wired) printer

Tags: printer, connection

I have a windows 7 pc with a USB realtek rtl8187b and a canon mp190. Even formated it a week ago (though the problem happened before already). Whenever i turn on the printer, my connection goes down and the status light of the realtek stays on permanently. The internet generally comes back after i take it from the pc, and plug it in again. Any idea? thks!

Answer (score 1):

PCs usually have USB ports from different internal USB hubs. Try changing the USB port of one of the devices.

Comment: yeah.. ive tryed that already, but i didnt try everyone of them.. i'll get back after i really try that option.

Comment: just tried a different one, and it disconnected. I disabled the network adaptor and enabled it again. The internet connectio was restored. Unplugged the printer's USB, plugged it in the same USB port and no problem at all with the internet. It really pisses me off, cuz it seems it doesn't have a pattern (except that when the PC disconnects its the printer's fault).

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer plugged into the same circuit as the computer/router? Try plugging it into a different outlet, preferably one on a different circuit (try a plug in a different room, perhaps with an extension cable).

Comment: do u think that might be the problem? what has the electricity to do with the two not working well together? shouldn't that be something around software or PC hardware?

Comment: @StinkyCat, the problem could simply be too much power drain on the same circuit.

Comment: oh u meant usb outlets lol im trying it right now

Comment: and no. cuz if i go to the device manager and disable and enable it right away, the light starts blinking again and connects. so i think we can rule out the power question, no?